# Error Serving WOFF File in PHP - file_get_contents versus readfile

Tags: php, server, mime-types, woff, http-content-length

I am trying to serve a WOFF font file in PHP.

First I set the Content-Type header:

```
header("Content-Type: application/font-woff");
```

Then I try the following:

This works fine (the file is properly served to the user, and the Content-Length header matches the file size):

```
readfile("path/to/font.woff");
```

But this doesn't (the script completes without error, but I receive an "octet stream" error in the browser, and the Content-Length header is 0):

```
echo file_get_contents("path/to/font.woff");
```

Why am I receiving an error using file_get_contents? I am using Windows 10, IIS Express 10, and PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

You should check your server logs and your log_level. file_get_contents returns false if there was an error reading the file. I've tested it right now and `echo(false)` returns an empty string. In this case the response body would be empty (and the content length be 0).

The reason, that file_get_content is failing could either be an incorrect path or, that the file content cannot be interpreted as an string. File_get_contents tries to create a string out of the file. It could be, that this does not work with a woff file. But I'm not shure on this. You should check the logs (E_WARNING log level).